# How would I make specific boxes changes color upon clicking on them?

Tags: javascript, debugging

I'd like to change color of more than one box to purple upon clicking on it.  With my current code below, only one box gets colored purple when clicking on it.

I've tried so many different ways to make it work in terms of upon you clicking on any number of boxes, the box should turn purple, but all my attempts have failed.

What am I doing wrong?

```js
function createBoxesDynamically() {
    var tileLength = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11);
    console.log("tileLength " + tileLength);

    var box = new Array(tileLength);
    console.log("box" + box);

    for (var i = 0; i < box.length; i++) {
        box[i] = "box";
    }

    for (var j = 0; j < box.length; j++) {
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.id = "box";
        document.body.appendChild(div);
    }

    var boxes = document.querySelector("[id^=box]");

    boxes.addEventListener("click", function () {
        boxes.style.backgroundColor = "purple";
    });
}

createBoxesDynamically();
```

```css
    #box {
        border: 1px solid;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        background-color: green;
    }
```

Comment: We'll also need to see the relevant HTML this is operating on.

Comment: @ScottHunter There's no HTML, what I'm doing above is completely dynamic.  In other words, I have no divs or anything like that declared in my html file.

Comment: For one thing, no two elements should have the same id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have multiple elements with identical `id` values, that's why no matter which box you click, the first one is always affected, your `.querySelector()` call stops looking after finding the first match.

Instead, move the code that sets up the event handler inside the loop where the box is being created and just use `this` in the `click` callback to have the callback act upon the box that was clicked. No `id` necessary. And, because you won't be using `id`s, you don't need your array or the first loop.

In general, stay away from coding solutions that rely on `id`s. Yes, they seem precise and easy to use at first, but what you'll find (and you already are) is that they create very brittle solutions that don't scale very well. There are many other ways of referencing and styling elements besides an `id`.

You should also try to avoid inline styling of elements (setting up styles directly on the `style` property) as this usually leads to duplication of code and therefore makes the code more difficult to read and maintain. Use CSS classes for as much as you can.

```js
function createBoxesDynamically() {
    var tileLength = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11);
    console.log("tileLength " + tileLength);

    for (var j = 0; j < tileLength; j++) {
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.classList.add("box");  // Add the CSS class to the element
        div.addEventListener("click", function () {
          this.classList.add("clickColor");;
        });
        document.body.appendChild(div);
    }
}

createBoxesDynamically();
```

```css
/* Use Classes instead of IDs */
.box {
        border: 1px solid;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        background-color: green;
}

.clickColor { background-color: #800080; }
```